# How to delete the X oldest items in a table in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a rolling version system, where users can make keep several versions of something, but once it goes past 10 versions, it deletes the oldest item(s).

This is what I want to do, but the syntax is invalid (can't use the row count in `LIMIT`):

```sql
with version_ids as (
  select rd.id from reels_data rd, reels r where r.owner_id = '7f92dcc6-f906-418a-aee0-074b297bfb52' and reel_id = 40 order by version
)
delete from reels_data where id in (select id, count(*) as rows from version_ids limit 10 - rows);
```

There's still a lot I don't know about Postgres, so I imagine there's some better way to do this.

Comment: `from reels_data rd, reels r` this does not seem right. Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: It's a cross join, it works fine. I'm only using this to access `r.owner_id` to prevent users from messing with other people's data. I'll edit the column name to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you could list the existinɡ versions for a user in descending order, skip the first 10 (i.e the 10 latest) and delete the rest:

```
DELETE FROM reels_data
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM reels
    WHERE reels.owner_id = '7f92dcc6-f906-418a-aee0-074b297bfb52'
    ORDER BY version DESC /* assuming no null versions */
    OFFSET 10
)
```

If a user has less than 10 versions, the `OFFSET` will make it so nothing is returned (and deleted).

---

If you're looking to do this for multiple users in a single query you'll need to use a window function (presumably `rank()` or `row_number()`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just keep the 10 newer :

- Select the 10 newer's ids by ordering by version and using LIMIT
- Delete all from your table where id not in what you selected

Comment: There would be a catastrophic loss of data if someone passed the API a wrong value, the first `SELECT` statement returned nothing, then `DELETE` would wipe out everything. And `DELETE` has no way of using joins to check data from another table.

Comment: @ffxsam: `DELETE`s can use joins (in postgresql), with the `USING` clause.

Comment: Select the 10 newer's ids by ordering by version and using LIMIT. I don't get how you can have no return except if you have no version in you database. I just thought about something like :

`delete from reels_data where id not in (select rd.id from reels_data rd, reels r where r.owner_id = '7f92dcc6-f906-418a-aee0-074b297bfb52' and reel_id = 40 order by version limit 10)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
delete from reels_data rd
    where rd.id < (select rd2.id
                   from reels_data rd2
                   where rd2.owner = rd.owner
                   order by rd2.id desc
                   limit 1 offset 9
                  );
```

The subquery gets the 10th largest `id` for each owner.  Anything smaller is deleted.  If there are not 10, then the subquery returns `NULL` and nothing gets deleted for that owner.

Answer (score 0):

Much quicker **NOT IN** than Marth's:

```
DELETE FROM tableName
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tableName
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
)
```